# How to prevent XY Graph from opening during simulation in Simulink

Tags: simulink

I have a Simulink simulation containing a [`XY Graph`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/xygraph.html) block. When I start a simulation, it automatically opens an XY Graph, but I do not want this. I just want to be able to double-click on it after a Simulation if I wish to see its content, as I am also doing with `scope`s. I know that in a `scope`'s settings, there is the option

> Open at simulation start

I guess that there should be a similar setting to my `XY Graph` but I cannot find where it is. How can I prevent it from opening during a simulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this block is implemented by an s-function that creates the figure (without providing much option there). So, the best that you could do would be to add code into a block (or model) callback to set the figure to not visible. Below is an example of how to find the figure handle and set it to not visible. This kind of thing can be found in sfunxy.m

Example:

```
set(get_param('your/xygraph/path','UserData'), 'Visible', 'off');
```

You would then need to run the following command to view the data (or create a shortcut).

```
set(get_param('your/xygraph/path','UserData'), 'Visible', 'on');
```

Obviously, this is not ideal. :)